# Book about ordination in ecology

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, multidimensional-scaling, ecology, canonical-correlation

I am looking for a book that would cover a lot of different ordinations techniques (indirect gradient analysis e.g. PCA, CA, DCA, MDS, nMDS but also direct gradient analysis e.g. CCA, CCorA, RDA) with applications in ecology (with R would be better) and mostly focusing on these methods.

I think " Numerical Ecology " by Legendre & Legendre (https://www.elsevier.com/books/numerical-ecology/legendre/978-0-444-53868-0#) would be relevant but it seems to cover a very extensive number of topics. Any other idea ?

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with it, but this book has come up in discussions: https://www.fbbva.es/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/dat/DE_2013_multivariate.pdf (free pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but I think I'll just add something here so that it can be referred to later, especially since it's pointed enough that it deserves a bit of attention.

I would suggest *Numerical Ecology* (your initial choice), especially since the authors have come out with a [3rd English edition in 2012](https://www.elsevier.com/books/numerical-ecology/legendre/978-0-444-53868-0). I also suggest this book since it comes with a companion book of sorts, *Numerical Ecology with R* (which also recently saw a [new edition](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319714035) last year) and is kind of the 'practical' R version of *Numerical Ecology* (which would be the theory book, if you will).

Zuur. et al.'s 2007 book *[Analysing Ecological Data](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387459677)* also covers CCA and PCA analyses. It covers a lot of detail of analysing ecological data (as the title implies), but it doesn't have examples in R.

Both books (*Numerical Ecology* and *Analysing Ecological Data*) are cited a lot, so they're good places to start.